# How can I crop the detected rectangular area after performing object detection through tflite model?

Tags: java, android, object-detection, crop, tensorflow-lite

I am a beginner Android developer. Object detection was performed through the tensorflow lite object detection model and the detected object rectangle was drawn.

But I'm having trouble trying to crop only the detected area (square). I made a method that generates a Bitmap by specifying the coordinates of the rect, but it doesn't crop properly.
Is there a way to crop only the detected area using a rectf or otherwise? Any help would be appreciated

There are values ​​such as left, top, bottom, right that need to be cropped to location. I tried to crop with Bitmap.createBitmap() with these values, but a blank screen keeps appearing and cropping does not work. If there is another way to crop without using RectF, or if you can help me, please help....

cropToFrameTransform = new Matrix();
frameToCropTransform.invert(cropToFrameTransform);

```
    trackingOverlay = (OverlayView) findViewById(R.id.tracking_overlay);
    trackingOverlay.addCallback(
            new DrawCallback() {
                @Override
                public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas) {
                    tracker.draw(canvas);
                    if (isDebug()) {
                        tracker.drawDebug(canvas);
                    }
                }
            });

    tracker.setFrameConfiguration(previewWidth, previewHeight, sensorOrientation);
}

@Override
protected void processImage() {
    ++timestamp;
    final long currTimestamp = timestamp;
    trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();

    // No mutex needed as this method is not reentrant.
    if (computingDetection) {
        readyForNextImage();
        return;
    }
    computingDetection = true;
    LOGGER.i("Preparing image " + currTimestamp + " for detection in bg thread.");

    rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);

    readyForNextImage();

    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(rgbFrameBitmap, frameToCropTransform, null);
    // For examining the actual TF input.
    if (SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP) {
        ImageUtils.saveBitmap(croppedBitmap);
    }
    runInBackground(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LOGGER.i("Running detection on image " + currTimestamp);
                    final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    final List<Detector.Recognition> results = detector.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);
                    lastProcessingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

                    cropCopyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap); 
                    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cropCopyBitmap);
                    final Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
                    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

                    float minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;
                    switch (MODE) {
                        case TF_OD_API:
                            minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;
                            break;
                    }

                    final List<Detector.Recognition> mappedRecognitions =
                            new ArrayList<Detector.Recognition>(); 

                    for (final Detector.Recognition result : results) {
                        final RectF location = result.getLocation();
                        if (location != null && result.getConfidence() >= minimumConfidence) { 
                            canvas.drawRect(location, paint);

                            cropToFrameTransform.mapRect(location);
                            result.setLocation(location);
                            mappedRecognitions.add(result);


                            float location_top = location.top;
                            float location_left = location.left;
                            float location_right = location.right;
                            float location_bottom = location.bottom;
                            float location_width = location.width();
                            float location_height = location.height();
```

//It seems to be cropped from the original with the coordinates of this location.

```
                            //mappedRecognitions : [[0] BusinessCard (70.3%) RectF(373.3333, 46.25, 536.6666, 425.0)]
                            try {
                             

                                float confidence = result.getConfidence();


                                crop_result_list = new Detector.Recognition(
                                        "0", "BusinessCard",confidence,location); //location is 


                                Bitmap crop_image = cropBitmap_testing(cropCopyBitmap);//failed crop
                               //Bitmap crop_image = pleaseCrop(cropCopyBitmap, location);
                            

                                crop_result_list.setCrop(crop_image);

                            }catch (Exception err){
                                System.out.println("Fail image crop");
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    tracker.trackResults(mappedRecognitions, currTimestamp);
                    trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();

                    computingDetection = false;

                    runOnUiThread(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    showFrameInfo(previewWidth + "x" + previewHeight);
                                    showCropInfo(cropCopyBitmap.getWidth() + "x" + cropCopyBitmap.getHeight());
                                    showInference(lastProcessingTimeMs + "ms");
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852127/how-to-crop-bitmap . The first one Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height) . If you have the points and you can calculate the distance between points then you can crop it.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! As you said, I wrote a method and tried to crop it, but it failed. Could you please find the wrong thing in the method I wrote? Are the values ​​of x and y wrong?                                                                                         public Bitmap cropBitmap(Bitmap original, RectF rect){
        int x = (int)rect.left;
        int y = (int)rect.top;
        int width = (int)rect.width();
        int height = (int)rect.height();
        Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(original,x,y,width,height);
        return croppedBmp;
    }